# Switching 12v with an arduino

Tags: arduino, switches

I would like to use my arduino pins to control a 12 V light that has its own power supply. So what I need is something that can be used as a switch (here is in pink color) but I don't know much about electronics so I don't know what part to put there. I don't want to use transistors as they require to use the same ground potential.

[image]

Comment: "*I don't want to use transistors as they require to use the same ground potential*", and why is this a *problem* for you? Or is this just a random *preference* you've acquired?

Comment: I need the arduino to be on always and the car battery requires a key to let the power trough so conneting it together would break the power at the arduino

Comment: You can still share the same ground, regardless of if the battery is powering something up or not. If the Arduino is on a separate supply, then it can still be always on, and have the whole circuit share a ground. Use transistors. That's the best way

Comment: so i need to connect the grounds and replace the pink part with a transistor(with resistors) and i'm good to go?

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity and robustness, use a *relay*.  That's basically a electrically-controlled mechanical switch.

You can get modules that contain relays and that are controlled directly from digital outputs.  You can also make your own circuit to do that.  Driving a relay from a digital signal has been discussed many times here before.  Look around.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make ground common and use logic level power mosfet. If you don't want to make ground common then use relay

**Option 1:** Mosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAG3WO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Option 2:** Relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvgAQg.png)</sup>

Comment: The user is cleary a novice so this answer is not likely to help at all. I didn't downvote but if you add a schematic for both of your solutions I imagine that you may get some upvotes. There is a CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and it will save editable schematics inline with your post.

Comment: 100 Ω pull-down on the gate of the NMOS, really?

Comment: sorry, it should be greater than 1 mega

Comment: A IRF540 is inappropriate for the use in your first schematic.  It is only specified for 10 V gate drive.  It is not meant to be driven from a digital signal, not even a 5 V one.  Also, R1 is barely needed at all.  Since the arduino isn't a FET driver, R1 could easily be left off.  10 kOhms is way too high.

Comment: If you would've swapped the 100 Ω pull-down with the 10 kΩ then it would've made sense. Keeping the 10 kΩ and replacing 100 Ω with 1 MΩ is really bad. The RC constant (gate capacitance and your resistors) will be unnecessarily large. - To be crystal clear, your 10 kΩ should be ~100 Ω and your 1 MΩ should be ~10 kΩ.

Comment: In your relay circuit, you don't show the power supply for the lamp.